Using Channel<T> Across Processes
Is there any way to use the .NET Channel API across processes? I was thinking about the synchronization primitives that can receive a name and therefore can be accessed by any process in the same machine. There doesn’t seem to be a way to achieve this with channels, or is there?

System.Threading.Channels.Channel<T> is not an IPC primitive; if that's the one you mean, then: "no". Some random options (among many): sockets, named pipes, gRPC, some external queue server or database.

Thanks, Marc, I know about those and many more, I even wrote a post about it many years ago. I was just curious about Channel because I think that is missing to make it indeed an IPC alternative

@MarcGravell: BTW, why don't you turn your comment into an answer, and I'll accept it?

@RicardoPeres .NET's Channel is equivalent to Go's channel and has nothing to do with IPC in either language. In both languages channels are used for ordered asynchronous communication between .. things. Goroutines, tasks, threads etc.

If by Channel<T> you mean System.Threading.Channels.Channel<T>, then no: that is not intended for use as an IPC mechanism, and it contains zero code to implement such.
Random options here might include sockets, named-pipes, gRPC, or an external database or queue-server - but many other options exist too.
